# read /proc/stats multiple times in c

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

I'd like to read /proc/stats multiple times in seconds. As an example I would use:

```C
fp = fopen ("/proc/stats", "r");
while (1){
  fseek(fp,0,SEEK_SET);
  for(i=0 ; i<5 ; i++) {
    fgets(buff, LINE_BUFFER, fp);
    buff[strlen(buff)-1] = '\0'
    printf("Line <%s>\n", buff);
  }
  sleep (0.2);
}
```

but clearly I always get the same value. Do I need to close and re-open the file to see the changes?

Thanks

Comment: The stuff under `/proc` usually aren't real files, they are in general not seekable. Is `/proc/stats` an exception?

Comment: Oddly enough, the system I'm currently on (Lubuntu) doesn't even have /proc/stats.

Comment: @Linuxios That could be a typo, mine has `/proc/stat`, but not `/proc/stats`, as I just checked.

Answer (score 5):

Yes you need to reopen it. To avoid race conditions, the contents of most /proc files are fixed on open.

Comment: +1 This is correct - /proc filesystems are directly maintained by the kernel.  On open the kernel will provide the process a static copy of the data if the data in question is dynamically changing.  Likewise, if a /proc filesystem had directories, opendir()/readdir() get a static copy of the directory.  Entries are not guaranteed to be valid for the same reason. For readdir() this is true for any directory. /proc or not.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just open()/read()/seek, which bypasses FILE/flush altogether.